# Program for helping learning languages

Tags: text, machine-learning, utilization

If you are looking at a book in its original language and an English translation both available for free online, and you are following along side by side, but want to see each sentence of the original on the top or bottom of the English translation, is there some sort of programming that converts two pieces of text so that they converge and you can see the translation sentence by sentence, as in there is a sentence in one language then on the the next line is the same sentence in the other language?

I've noticed that following along side by side is a bit hard because you have to move your eyes side to side, because there is a bit of travel distance for your eyes and sometimes you lose track and take a few seconds to find the right spot and it gets tiring.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What's exactly your question?

Comment: Basically I want to know if there is a program that takes two pieces of text and then converges them into one by having each corresponding sentence on top of each other.